# Why are functions with vanishing normal derivative dense in smooth functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, manifolds-with-boundary

**Question**

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with piecewise smooth boundary. Why are smooth functions with vanishing normal derivative dense in $C^\infty(M)$ in the $H^1$ norm?

Here I define $C^\infty(M)$ to be those functions which have all orders of derivative continuous on $M$ and smooth in its interior. For example, $(x\mapsto \sin(\pi x))\in C^\infty([0,1])$ but $(x\mapsto \sqrt{x})\notin C^\infty([0,1])$.

I have [crossposted this to MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286412/why-are-functions-with-vanishing-normal-derivative-dense-in-smooth-functions).

---

**Background**

This is inspired by my belief that the form domain of the Friedrichs extension of the Neumann Laplacian on $M$ is equal to $H^1(M)$. If my belief is wrong, I would certainly accept as answer a counterexample, preferably with some discussion/references.

Here are the approaches I'm exploring.

- Given $u\in C^\infty(M)$ construct a function that agrees away from an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\partial M$, but has been modified to have zero normal derivative. This is described below, but runs into some trouble at corners and with smoothing.
- Given $u\in C^\infty(M)$, find some $\eta$ supported on an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\partial M$ such that $\nabla\eta|_{\partial M}$ is equal to the projection of $\nabla u|_{\partial M}$ onto the normal direction and $\eta$ and $|\nabla\eta|$ uniformly bounded in $\epsilon$. Then $u - \eta$ will be the desired approximation and uniform boundedness will imply $\|u - (u-\eta)\|_{H^1}\to 0$. I'm not sure if this is a search for an integrable harmonic vector field or if it's a constrained optimization problem.
- Simply show that any $u\in C^\infty(M)$ that is perpendicular to all smooth functions with vanishing normal derivative must be zero. In order to do this, I think it still runs into the same fundamental difficulty as the others, which is constructing functions with vanishing normal derivative supported on an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the boundary.

(I'm also happy to simply have a reference to follow up. A reference for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be fine, too, and just a partition of unity away from a Riemannian manifold.)

---

**Current Approach**

The approach I'm considering right now is an elaboration on possibility (2) from my list. The sketch is: set the boundary condition that $\nabla\eta$ on the boundary be equal to the normal component of $\nabla u$ and find an integrable harmonic vector field $E$ satisfying that boundary condition. Then cut off $E$ so it is only supported in a neighborhood of $\partial M$, and let $\eta$ be so that $E = \nabla\eta$.

Intuition is that the maximum principle will control $|E|$ and $|\eta|$, so that $\eta$ will be bounded above in the $H^1$ norm by a constant times the volume of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\partial M$.

Another approach is inspired by zhw's comment below: approximate $\nabla u$ among $L^2$ vector fields, multiply it by a cutoff function so it is supported in the interior of $M$, and then integrate it to approximate $u$. This should work with some tweaking in $[0,1]$ but I'm not sure how well it will work in general.

---

**Older work**

My approach has been as follows. The intuition is to take an arbitrary smooth function, restrict it to the complement of a collar neighborhood, then extend the restriction to the collar neighborhood so that the value is constant on inward-normal geodesics. However I'm running into issues at corners.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be such that $\{p\in M\ |\ d(p,\partial M) < \epsilon\}$ is a collar neighborhood of $\partial M$. Let $e_\epsilon(p)$ for $p\in\partial M$ be the smaller of $\epsilon$ or the greatest time parameter such that the inward normal geodesic collides with no other inward normal geodesic. Let $N$ be the set of inward normal vectors on $\partial M$ whose lengths are no greater than $e_\epsilon$. The interior of the set $\operatorname{exp}(N)$ is foliated by geodesics. Edit- Note this is not necessarily true if the manifold has inward corners.

Given a smooth, continuous function $u$ on $M$, define $\bar{u}$ to be the restriction of $u$ in the complement of $\operatorname{exp}(N)$ and on each geodesic leaf of the interior of $\operatorname{exp}(N)$ define $\bar{u}$ to take the value that $u$ takes on the inward limit of that leaf.

Here's trouble. As $\bar{u}$ need not be smooth, I'd like to mollify it. Edit- I had a detail incorrect. A standard mollifier produces a function defined on compact subsets of the interior of $M$. So the mollifier has to be modified. One idea I'm following up on is varying the support of the mollifying function based on distance to $\partial M$. I'm skeptical, as varying the mollifying function will add another component to the gradient, but if it works I'll post as an answer.

Comment: I think the word "vanishing" has vanished in the first paragraph (currently: "with normal derivative"). Also "smooth, continuous" is redundant right?

Comment: @Dap Good catch, thanks. I mean to indicate those functions which are continuous on all of $M$ and smooth on the interior, as opposed to functions which are smooth on the interior but don't necessarily extend to continuous functions on $M$.

Comment: I think this would be appropriate for mathoverflow as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm going to put a bounty on it here and then xpost to MO if there's still no answer when the bounty expires.

Comment: Why are you sure this result holds? Especially with inward corners

Comment: @Bananach I have "folk belief" that on compact manifolds with sufficiently regular boundary, the form domain of the Friedrichs extension of the Neumann Laplacian is equal to $H^1$. Searching for proof is spurring the line of inquiry that lead to this question. If my belief is wrong, then I think a counterexample and discussion of conditions when it does hold would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Certainly I do need to consider inward corners more carefully.

Comment: I think, this is already false for $M=[0,1]$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you have a counterexample in mind? Seems to me the proof method I suggest in the last section should work for $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Niel: Just take the sequence of linear functions $f_n(x)=nx$. When I tried to approximate by functions with zero derivative at $0$, the $H^1$-norm of the difference was diverging to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Try your method and see what you get.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at -- why take a sequence of functions and argue that the difference of the approximations diverges? To show that vanishing-normal-derivative functions are dense, shouldn't one take an arbitrary smooth function on $[0,1]$ and construct an approximating sequence that converges to it in the $H^1$ norm?

Comment: @MoisheCohen No, it works on $[0,1]. $ Just approximate $f'$ in $L^2$ by a smooth $g$ with support in $(0,1).$ Then consider $G(x)=f(0)+ \int_0^x g.$

Comment: @Neal: Sorry, what I wrote was nonsense. The correct statement is that density fails for $M=[0,1]$ if $C^{\infty}(M)$ means smooth on the interior, continuous on $M$. An example is $f(x)=x^{1/2}$, since $f'(x)\notin L^2([0,1])$. I think, $C^{\infty}(M)$ has to be defined by embedding $M$ in a smooth open manifold $M'$ of the same dimension and then  restricting functions in $C^{\infty}(M')$ to $M$.

Comment: @zhw.: See the corrected comment.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks, I see what you mean. I would define $C^\infty(M)$ as functions whose derivatives must all also extend continuously to $\bar{M}$. I *think* this coincides with your definition, but it may be a slightly larger class of functions.

Comment: How to prove the same statement for the space of analytic functions on the closed unit disc with the uniform convergence topology? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following construction works. Analogous to the $n=1$ case from the comments, the idea is to approximate $\nabla u$ by compactly supported $\mathbf{g}_n$ and construct a suitable sequence $u_n$ such that each $\nabla u_n = \mathbf{g}_n.$ I will use some results from the following reference.

*Maz’ya, Vladimir G.*, [**Sobolev spaces. With applications to elliptic partial differential equations. Transl. from the Russian by T. O. Shaposhnikova**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-15564-2), Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften 342. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-15563-5/hbk; 978-3-642-15564-2/ebook). xxviii, 866 p. (2011). [ZBL1217.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1217.46002).

**Definition** (1.1.8): We say $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ is *starshapred with respect to a ball $B \subset \Omega$* if for all $x \in B$ and $y \in \Omega,$ we have the segment $[x,y] \subset \Omega.$

It is shown in 1.1.9 (Lemma 1) that if $\Omega$ satisfies the cone property, then it can be written as a union of finitely many domains which are startshared with respect to a ball. Note this also holds for $C^{0,1}$ domains, and it should include any reasonable definition of a piecewise smooth boundary.

**Theorem** (1.1.10): If $\Omega$ is bounded and starshapred with respect to a ball $B_{\delta}$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ then we have
$$ u(x) = \delta^{-n} \int_{B_{\delta}} \varphi\left(\frac{y}{\delta}\right) u(y) \,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{\Omega} \frac{\mathbf{f}(x;r,\theta)}{r^{n-1}} \cdot \nabla u(y)\,\mathrm{d}y $$
for almost every $x \in \Omega,$ where $r = |y-x|,$ $\theta = (y-x)r^{-1},$ $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(B_1),$ and $\mathbf{f}$ is smooth and $\Bbb R^n$-valued such that
$$ |\mathbf{f}(x;r,\theta)| \leq c \left(\frac{\operatorname{diam}(\Omega)}{\delta}\right)^{n-1}.$$

I will omit a detailed proof (which is in the text), but the idea is to fix a mollifier $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(B_1)$ and set $\varphi_{\delta}(y) = \delta^{-n} \varphi(y/\delta).$ Then for $u$ smooth we have the Taylor representation
$$ u(x) = u(y) + \int_0^1 (1-t) \sum_{i=1}^n D^iu(y+t(x-y))(x_i-y_i) \,\mathrm{d}t, $$
for all $x \in \Omega$ and $y \in B_{\delta}.$ Multiplying by $\varphi_{\delta}(y)$ and integrating over $y \in B_{\delta}$ gives
$$ u(x) = \delta^{-n} \int_{B_{\delta}} \varphi\left(\frac{y}{\delta}\right) u(y) \,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{B_{\delta}} \varphi_{\delta}(y)\int_0^1 (1-t) \sum_{i=1}^n D^iu(y+t(x-y))(x_i-y_i) \,\mathrm{d}t \,\mathrm{d}y, $$
and the second term can be made to be of the right form by switching to $(r,\theta)$ coordinates. If $\delta=1$ one obtains
$$ f_i(x;r,\theta) = - \theta_i \int_r^{\infty} \varphi(x+ \rho\theta) \rho^{n-1} \,\mathrm{d}\rho, $$
which one can check satisfies the desired properties.

Using the above we can prove the reslt in the case when $M = \Omega$ is starsharped with respect to some ball $B_{\delta}.$ Let $\mathbf{g}_n \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega;\Bbb R^n)$ such that $\mathbf{g}_n \to \nabla u$ in $L^2.$ Then define
$$ u_n(x) = \delta^{-n} \int_{B_{\delta}} \varphi\left(\frac{y}{\delta}\right) u(y) \,\mathrm{d}y + \int_{\Omega} \frac{\mathbf{f}(x;r,\theta)}{r^{n-1}} \cdot \mathbf{g}_n(y)\,\mathrm{d}y. $$
A calculation gives $\nabla u_n = \mathbf{g}_n,$ so we have $L^2$ convergence of the derivatives. For $L^2$ convergence this is essentially proved in 1.1.11, but since the text is light on the details I will include a proof. Applying Hölder and Fubini we have
$$\begin{split} \int_{\Omega} |u(x)-u_n(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d} x &=\int_{\Omega} \left| \int_{\Omega} \frac{\mathbf{f}(x;r,\theta)}{r^{n-1}} \cdot (\nabla u(y) - \mathbf{g}_n(y))\,\mathrm{d}y \right|^2 \,\mathrm{d} x  \\
&\leq\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega} \frac1{r^{1-n}} \,\mathrm{d} y \int_{\Omega} \left|\mathbf{f}(x;r,\theta) \cdot (\nabla u(y) - \mathbf{g}_n(y))\right|^2 \frac1{r^{n-1}}\,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d} x \\
&\leq C \int_{\Omega} \left(\int_{\Omega} |x-y|^{1-n} \,\mathrm{d} x\right)^2 |\nabla u(y) - \mathbf{g}_n(y)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}y,
\end{split}$$
which converges to zero as $n \to \infty$ noting that $\int_{\Omega} |x-y|^{1-n} \,\mathrm{d} x \leq C(\Omega)$ uniformly in $y.$ Hence it follows that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega).$

For the general case we can using a patching argument; let $\{\Omega_i\}$ be a finite covering of $M$ by subsets which can be identified by means of a diffeomorphism with a starshaped domain in $\Bbb R^n.$ Let $\{\psi_i\}$ be a subordinate partition of unity, approximate $u$ on each $\Omega_i$ by $u_n^{(i)}$ as above and set $u_n = \sum_i \psi_i u_n^{(i)}.$ Note this is only a sketch as it depends on the precise formulation of a piecewise smooth boundary, but I will leave you to fill in the details.